# Jquery select all rows and columns matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table matrix with checkboxes in columns and rows. Each row and column have a "header" checkbox which triggers a select all on the relevant row or column.

Right now I can achieve what I want with no less than 6 separate jQuery click functions...

**HTML**

```
<tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Column 1 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="c1Button" class="c1" /></th>
        <th>Column 2 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="c2Button" class="c2" /></th>
        <th>Column 3 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="c3Button" class="c3" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="r1Button" class="r1" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c1 r1" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c2 r1" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c3 r1" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="r2Button" class="r2" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c1 r2" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c2 r2" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c3 r2" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Row 3 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="r3Button" class="r3" /></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="c1 r3" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="c2 r3" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="c3 r3" value=""></td>
    </tr>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#c1Button").click(function () {
        $(".c1").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
$("#c2Button").click(function () {
        $(".c2").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
$("#c3Button").click(function () {
        $(".c3").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
$("#r1Button").click(function () {
        $(".r1").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
$("#r2Button").click(function () {
        $(".r2").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
$("#r3Button").click(function () {
        $(".r3").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
```

I'm not well versed with jQuery and my Googling and embarrassing attempts at making this one function have all failed.

Tim

Comment: make a jsfiddle for us :)

Comment: Please describe(update) more your question about your goal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1,000 ways to skin a cat. This might work
Add classes column and row with pseudo-attributes as follows

```
<tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Column 1 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="c1Button" class="c1 column" colid="c1" /></th>
        <th>Column 2 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="c2Button" class="c2 column" colid="c2" /></th>
        <th>Column 3 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="c3Button" class="c3 column" colid="c3" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="r1Button" class="r1 row" rowid="r1" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c1 r1" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c2 r1" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c3 r1" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="r2Button" class="r2 row" rowid="r2" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c1 r2" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c2 r2" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="c3 r2" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Row 3 Heading <input type="checkbox" id="r3Button" class="r3 row" rowid="r3" /></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="c1 r3" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="c2 r3" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="c3 r3" value=""></td>
    </tr>
```

Then with jQuery

```
$(".column").click(function(){
    var colid = $(this).attr("colid");
    $("." + colid).prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
$(".row").click(function(){
    var rowid = $(this).attr("rowid");
    $("." + rowid).prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on "var colid = this.attr("colid");". http://jsfiddle.net/ArTy4/

Comment: Sorry didn't wrap this as jQuery object. Fixed and tested on jsfiddle. Worked =) Please see edited answer for new code

Comment: Thank-you!! It works :) I know this is outside the scope of the question, but I'm unable to replace the "select all" checkboxes with a  button. Aren't we just using the "click" attribute of the checkbox?? http://jsfiddle.net/ArTy4/3/ Appreciate if you can help with this one as well :)

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, I can see why it doesn't work. I think I'll try and style the checkbox as a button. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the markup you can change the jquery code as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr:first input').click(function () {
        var colno = 1+Number.parseFloat($(this).attr('id')[1]);
        $('td:nth-child(' + colno + ') input').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    $('td:nth-child(1) input').click(function (){
        var rowno = 1 + Number.parseFloat($(this).attr('id')[1]);
        $('tr:nth-child(' + rowno + ') input').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```